# Ошибка в запросе MySQL

Tags: веб-программирование, php, запрос, sql, mysql

Есть кусок кода, влекущий ошибку

```
@ $db=mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");

if (!$db)
{
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.";
}

mysql_select_db("books");
$query="select * from books where ".$_POST['searchtype']."like '%".$_POST['searchterm']."%'";
$result=mysql_query($query, $db) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

А именно ошибка в строке

```
$query="select * from books where ".$_POST['searchtype']."like '%".$_POST['searchterm']."%'";
```

Подскажите как устранить ошибку:

```
Unable to run query:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%Thomas%'' at line 1
```

Comment: [xdebug][1] вам в помощь


  [1]: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может не хватает пробела перед LIKE?

$query = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `" . $_POST['searchtype'] . "` LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchterm'] . "%'";

Comment: @ArtemRyzhov я исправил строку с запросом на следующую:

    $query="select * from books where ".$_POST['searchtype']." like '%" .$_POST['searchterm']. "%'";
да действительно упустил пробел перед `like`. @ArtemRyzhov а зачем нужны одинарные кавычки перед и после процента?

Comment: @ivan89 Эм... Синтаксис языка такой :) Если Вы напишете LIKE %sometext% , то получите ошибку

Comment: @ivan89

Почитайте  про [LIKE][1]  

  [1]: http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?15